# Trigger input event in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have Angular directive. Something like multiselect with search.
I want to clear query after click on clear icon.
Here is the code:

Template:

```
<div multiselect>
    <ul role="container">
        <li ng-repeat="(k,v) in ::propertyModel.getAllowedValues()" ng-show="isSelected(k);">
            {{v}}
            <span class="icon-close" ng-click="handleOptionRemove(k);" ng-show="!singleSelect"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div role="opener" class="icon-plus"></div>
    <div role="dropdown" class="closed">
        <div role="search">
            <span class="icon-magnifier"></span>
            <span class="icon-close" ng-click="handleSearchClear();"></span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Type to search">
        </div>
        <ul role="options">
            <li ng-repeat="(k,v) in ::propertyModel.getAllowedValues()" ng-show="!isSelected(k) && found(k);" ng-click="handleOptionSelect(k);">{{v}}</li>
            <li disabled ng-show="foundItems.length === 0 && queryString !== ''">There is no results found</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
var input= element.find('input');

[...]
function handleSearchInput(){
    scope.foundItems= [];
    scope.queryString= input[0].value.toLocaleUpperCase();
    for(var o in allowedValues) if(allowedValues.hasOwnProperty(o))
        if(allowedValues[o].toLocaleUpperCase().indexOf(scope.queryString)!== -1)
            scope.foundItems.push(o);
    scope.$apply();
}

[...]

scope.handleSearchClear = function(){
    input[0].value='';
    input.triggerHandler('input');
};

[...]
input.bind('input', handleSearchInput);
```

After click i have

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress[...]
```

on console.

How can i properly 'clear' this input's value?

Comment: Where's the directive defined in the HTML? Why not have an `ngModel` on the input and then clear it via `$scope`?

Comment: Directive is on higher DOM element.
Thi is a piece of HTML used by directive.
Everything works fine instead of this clear thing.

Ok, added _almost_ complete template

Comment: Use `$timeout` instead of calling `$apply()`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do in Jasmine tests to clear an element, perhaps this will be helpful:

```
var myInput = input[0]; // get the input somehow
angular.element(myInput).val('').trigger('input');
```

I do agree with tymeJV's suggestion to work from a model when possible. Then you'd end up with something like this:

```
$scope.model.myfieldval = '';
$scope.model.someOtherFieldVal = '';
$scope.form.myFormName.$setPristine();
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that i was jumped outside Angular context.

I was used `handleSearchInput` function in event callback fired by Angular itself and it was trigered with Angular's context, then i was forced this function with standard javascript context.
Or something like that ;)

Anyway there is a solution.

```
function handleSearchInput () {
    scope.$apply(function () {   //force Angular context (and scope)
        doSearch();
    });
}

function doSearch () {
    scope.foundItems = [];
    scope.queryString = input[0].value.toLocaleUpperCase();
    for (var o in allowedValues) if (allowedValues.hasOwnProperty(o)) {
        if (allowedValues[o].toLocaleUpperCase().indexOf(scope.queryString) !== -1) {
            scope.foundItems.push(o);
        }
    }
}

scope.handleSearchClear = function () {
    //always in context because of existing in scope
    input[0].value = '';
    doSearch();
};

input.bind('input', handleSearchInput);
```